# RVM in Elementary Luna OS

Tags: ruby, linux, terminal, rvm

I get the error "RVM is not a function" when trying to use it in Elementary Luna OS' terminal. There is an explanation here http://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal, but Elementary OS'terminal has no setting menu(!) -- so how can this be fixed in this OS?

Comment: See if you can find some settings with this help: https://gist.github.com/davidgomes/5162998

Comment: How are you sourcing RVM on your shell?

Answer (score 9):

Just open a terminal and paste this:

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

then execute this:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and it should work

Comment: The first line is appending the configuration to load rvm when you open your bash (assuming you're using bash of course) to your .bash_profile file.

The second command is just reloading your .bash_profile file without logging out and logging in again

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to approximate that setup by appending this to your `~/.bashrc` file (rvm.sh might not be the right name, but it's something like that). You may have to log in and out for it to take effect.

```
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Or instead append this, which should include everything under /etc/profile.d/. It should be very similar to checking the setting in gnome-terminal:

```
source /etc/profile
```